# Add job to printqueue - print locally

Tags: printqueue

I'm wondering how to create a print job from an application and send it to the printqueue of a printserver in C#. I then want to be able to retrieve and print the job on the server from another computer on a local printer when I want to.

My problem is that you have to assign a printername to a printqueue. But this shouldn't be necessary while the job is supposed to be printed locally.

I hope I make myself clear!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where are you going with this. `PrintQueue` is a queue of a **printer**. Not just some kind of waiting queue where you can add and remove jobs. If you put a job into a `PrintQueue`, it's going to be printed with the printer, associated with that `PrintQueue`.

Also please note that putting a job into queue means that document being printed is going to be converted to printer's driver-specific instructions. So, event if it would be possible to extract job from queue, you would **not** be able to print it on a different printer.